# Why does Helen throw away Theodore's letter for Frank?

Tags: plot-explanation, manhattan

In `S01E07` of [Manhattan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3231564/), Helen and Charlie travel to a nuclear reactor. There they meet Theodore Sinclair. With him they solve some crisis at the reactor. Shortly after, Theodore gives Helen a letter for Frank, which she throws away in a trashcan when arrived back in Manhattan.

Why does Helen throw away Theodore's letter for Frank?

Answer (score 2):

I think she sees him as competition. As she says to Charlie at the bar, she and Sinclair would both be minorities on The Hill and she must think he poses a threat to her.

Comment: I thought about that, but I can remember she says: as a women I'm glad I'm here (manhattan) so that I can do this work. She didn't had that opportunity else where. I got the idea she was perfectly happy with her current position and she didn't had any ambition (any more than that). So competition feels strange to me.